# Bragg diffraction form an "inclined" crystal plane: which angle to consider?

Tags: interference, geometric-optics, diffraction, x-rays, braggs-law

Consider Bragg diffraction form an "inclined" crystal plane (i.e. not perpendicular to the normal of the crystal). I was sure that the angle of diffraction $\theta$ in bragg's law **must always be measured with respect to the plane**.

Consulting the book of Halliday, Resnik, Krane first I found this picture, which confirm my assumption:

[image]

But then I also found the following exercise:

> In picture, first-order reflection from the reflection
> planes shown occurs when an x-ray beam of wavelength $0.260 nm$
> makes an angle $\theta=63.8°$ with the top face of the crystal. What is
> the unit cell size $a_0$?

[image]

I thought I must consider an angle $\alpha =\theta -45°=18.8°$ in bragg law and then $$a_0=\sqrt{2} \frac{ \lambda} {2 \sin \alpha}$$

Nevertheless I cheked on solution manual found online here : http://omega.altervista.org/extra/key%20to%20Physics.pdf

And I found the following solution:
[image]

So the angle used in Bragg law is still $\theta =63.8°$ ! How can it be correct?

Comment: It is an error in the solution manual. The surface is not important at all in x-ray diffraction, most of the x-ray intensities goes straight through.